# How to get content between the brackets using regex

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a string like so:

```
[abc] 12345 [abc] 67890 [/abc] [/abc]
```

I would like to match the content inside the brackets but NOT return a match if another opening bracket is found (e.g., `[abc]`). The function `/\[abc\](.*)\[\/abc\]/i` would output:

```
12345 [abc] 67890 [/abc]
```

But that's not what i want, because there's another opening bracket inside the text. The expected result would be:

```
67890
```

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: It's possible you'll need a full blown lexer (also called tokenizer) and parser system if you need to ask and solve complicated problems in such a grammar, for this problem a regex works but for harder ones it will not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just state that you don't want to allow brackets between your tags by using `[^\[\]]*` instead of `.*` (which would match *anything*, including brackets):

```
/\[abc\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/abc\]/i
```

Comment: +1 Just out of interest, what if I want to prevent something like: [a][/b]. Would I have to write more expressions or is there a way to alter the one you wrote so that only: [a][/a] is allowed. etc

Comment: @Touch: That would already be forbidden because no brackets at all are allowed between the tags. It gets interesting when you want to allow *other* tags, e. g. allow `[a] foo [b] bar [/b] baz [/a]` but forbid `[a] foo [a] bar [/a] baz [/a]`. For that you'll need lookahead assertions (or move away from regexes entirely into the parser world).

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
\[[^\/\]]*\]([^\[]*)\[\/[^\]]*\]
```

`\[` ---> character `[`

`[^\/\]]*` ---> read data till it reaches `]`  or `/`

`\]` ---> character `]`

`[^\[]*` ---> read data till character `[` reached

`()` ---> indicates group to we can select that group as `\1`

**Demo** http://rubular.com/r/shwsqTE61R

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new, but a shorter write:

```
$subject = '[abc] 12345 [abc] 67890 [/abc] [/abc]';
$pattern = '~\[abc]\K[^[]++(?=\[/abc])~i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this pattern:

```
(\d+)(?:\s*\[/abc\]\s*)+$
```

It will look from the right side and skip all ending tags like `[/abc]` and pick the very next number.